# How to check the status of notification permission in iOS app (flutter permission handler is not working)

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification

I'm making a mobile app using flutter and I'm making push notifications using FCM.

I'm using flutter permission handler package to know whether the users allow the notification or not when they see the notification permission dialog.

However, the permission handler is not working. Whether the user allows the permission or not, the permission handler always says that the user denied the notification permission.

I tried using the other package, but it doesn't work.
Please feel free to give me some any idea.

This is the code that I used.

```
var status = await Permission.notification.status;
      developer.log('status : ${status.isDenied}');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This package does not work on IOS out of the box. Referring to the documentation, you should add to your pod file this code to bottom block of the file:

```
# ...some flutter things
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    # ...
    # Start of the permission_handler configuration <----
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|

      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
             '$(inherited)',

        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',
      ]
    end
    # End of the permission_handler configuration <----
    # ...
  end
end
```

then flutter clean and it should work (tested today)

Answer (score 2):

For **Android** just try by adding **POST_NOTIFICATIONS** permission in your AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```